# What's the name for properties which are not managed by core data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Would I say "unmanaged" property? Is there a special name for this?

(talking about subclasses NSManagedObject with additional properties that are not in the data model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called transient properties.  You can define them in the model or you can just create them directly in the subclass.

Comment: Thanks Marcus! Now I understand both things at once. Great answer :-)